# How to constrain CSS to when a contained input has focus?

Tags: html, css

Assume I have a form input structured as follows:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="icon icon-search"></span>
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

is there a way, with CSS3, to apply a red border around the .wrapper div on a focus state on the input element?

```
.wrapper input:focus {
  border solid thin red;
}
```

puts the border on the input field but I want it on the containing div.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a css parent selector. Unfortunately that isn't currently available. The exact functionality you're looking for would need JavaScript or alternative HTML.

It looks like you want the border to surround the icon and the field but currently it is only surrounding the field? My suggestion would be to use the sibling selector like so: (From my example below i've moved the icon after the input)

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Helps with sizing calculations */
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.icon {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0;
    border: solid 1px transparent;
    border-left: none;
}
input {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    border-right: none;
}
input:focus {
    border-color: red;
    outline: 0;
}
input:focus + .icon {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text"/>
  <span class="icon icon-search"></span>
</div>
```